# Customising legend in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I’m trying to customise individual legend labels. In the example below, the legend contains two items. I’d like to make the text bold for only the second legend label.

Here’s a general outline of the code:

```
leg = plt.legend()
for text in leg.get_texts():
    text.set_fontweight...
```

Here’s a runnable example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X=range(10)
Y=range(100,110)
Z=range(105,115)
plt.plot(X,Y,label='normal')
plt.plot(X,Z,label='bold')
fontweights=['normal','bold']
leg=plt.legend()
for fw,text in zip(fontweights,leg.get_texts()):
    text.set_fontweight(fw)
plt.show()
```

Here's the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLgmr.png)

The plot produced shows that `set_fontweight()` changes both labels to bold. So is this a bug with `set_fontweight()`, or am I doing something wrong?

Similar functions, such as `text.set_color()`, can be used to modify legend labels individually.

Lastly, I’m using matplotlib version 3.2.2.

Thanks!

Comment: Weird. I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjsPe.png

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What version are you using?

Comment: 3.3.2. Though I'd try restarting your kernel to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this didn't work. Perhaps this is a bug fixed since the version I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have matplotlib 3.3.4 running, and get a bold and unbold legend entry - see attached image - so I think an upgrade should fix the problem.

[image]